# Can I set a PDF file's name in the viewer and/or URL in Chrome when using Javascript window.open on a dataURL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[PDF Viewer File Name/Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXcun.png)

[New Tab URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI0a0.png)

My code (Javascript) to open the tab is below:

```
function openPdfInNewTab(pdfData) {
  var file = new Blob([pdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' })
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  window.open(fileURL, 'test')
}
```